# Automate script on AWS aurora restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

We previously developed an on-premises application that relied on a script to perform certain operations on a MySQL database restart. This script was automated using the server system variable "init-file." However, we have now migrated to AWS, and our database is running on Aurora DB with MySQL compatibility. We are wondering if there is any equivalent way or option available to achieve the same automation for MySQL operations on Aurora DB.

We have already explored the option groups and parameter groups from the configuration settings, but we haven't found any direct solution. If there's an option we might have missed or if there's an alternative approach to automate these operations on Aurora DB, we would greatly appreciate your guidance. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/USER_Events.Messages.html